# Choice decision between different types of distributed frameworks available

Tags: rabbitmq, akka, apache-kafka, vert.x, distributed-system

How should one decide between rabbit mq, kafka , akka and vertx or chose a combination of a few of these?
I have a use case where I want to get huge (half a TB each day) market data using a java client API provided by an upstream.
We have currently implemented a distributed etl using Akka but want to know what other improvements or better choices or combination of choices(like akka+kafka) can be considered.

Comment: That decision is based on some things you only know. We don't. And even so, there can only be recommendations based on particular experiences and/or preferences, which are not suitable to ask over here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand this will differ as per different requirements and each one has something better and something not better than the other but it will be really helpful to get an insight on what basic features are available with each of these systems which help us take a decision to pick specific ones. Example: When to think for vert.x ?

Comment: Vert.x provides you with a lot of functionality; it's always a good start. I've tried Akka and I can't get it to work "distributed" without hassles (I'm thinking about something like Erlang here). In Vert.x you get a "real" distributed system (amen the issues that may arise by using Hazelcast and alikes). Spring Web Flux looks promising also (and the Spring platform is quite solid). As you can see, you have plenty of options...that's why deciding it's up to your knowledge and experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the choice between akka and vert.x the following Devoxx talk is to the point:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMv_8dxSqdE

It compares concurrency models, among them event bus (vert.x being the example) and actor systems (akka being the example).

In the summary slide (1h00m40s into the talk), the difference is summarised in that akka provides hierarchical supervision for error-handling, that being presented as an advantage over vert.x

akka-stream-kafka (formerly reactive-kafka) feels like a natural fit to bridge the two and we are happy users of it, but cannot comment on how it compares to rabbitmq.